# PHP mail headers not working properly

Tags: php, email

I am trying to create an email in PHP, but am having a problem constructing the headers.

I would like the `From` to be admin@example.com, and the other headers set as show below.

The problem is that when I send this email, the "from" part in the email client appears as:

> "admin@example.com rnReply-To: admin@example.com rnMIME-Version: 1.0 rnContent-Type: text/html"

This also inadvertently breaks the rest of the email because it doesn't recognise it as being html.

```
// email headers
$headers = 'From: admin@example.com \r\n';
$headers .= 'Reply-To: admin@example.com \r\n';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n';
```

Any idea on how I can fix these headers? Thanks.

Comment: `\r\n` parsed only in double quotes. Trailing spaces not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change following:

```
$headers = 'From: admin@example.com \r\n';
$headers .= 'Reply-To: admin@example.com \r\n';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n';
```

To this:

```
$headers = "From: admin@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: admin@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
```

Because `\r\n` should be in `""` (double quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$headers = 'From: admin@example.com' ."\n"; /* note double quote here*/
$headers .= 'Reply-To: admin@example.com' . "\n";/* note double quote here*/
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";/* note double quote here*/
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";/* here too*/
```

*edit (can't comment yet)*
Not sure how much experience you've had with writing scripts for emails but I had to create a system for our newsletter at work, and to come up with good headers that will pass spamblocks, etc, it takes some tinkering. 
You might want to look into mail frameworks you can use like Zend.

Also you try the "\r\n" for mime type, its been a while for me but I recall having mixed results with combinations of  "\n, \r\n, and \r\n\r\n"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out \r\n requires double quotes, and single quotes don't work.